# How to detect WinPcap library installed or not?

Tags: java, pcap, winpcap

I use Pcap4j library to capture packet.

If winpcap not installed, pcap4j only show some log, isn't throw exception.

I can't know the library initialization failed.

How to detect WinPcap library installed?

Answer (score 3):

If have installed the wpcap executable then check in "Add/Remove programs", If it is just DLL then check if DLL is [registered](https://serverfault.com/questions/576831/how-do-i-know-if-a-dll-is-registered)